# Проблема считывания матрицы с массива

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Labirint - [labirint.cpp](http://pastebin.com/6JDyAbyf)
labirint.h - [labirint.h](http://pastebin.com/mLWfqFH9)
матрица - [data.txt](http://pastebin.com/27cBpqAv)

Проблема сама в типах данных я так понимаю, но конкретно найти проблему не могу

При объявлении массива в заголовочном файле, результат такой: [image: инициализация в заголовочном файле]

При инициализации массива с файла, результат такой: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ну и понятно же что лабиринт не проходит алгоритм, не знаю из-за чего

Comment: Какой алгоритм должен пройти лабиринт? Что вы ожидаете получить и фактически получаете? Почему нет возможности найти ошибки с помощью отладчика?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю, что проблемы связаны с тем, что вы объявили внутри класса константы

```
const int sizeRow = 24;
const int sizeCol = 20;
```

но вместо этих констант в задании размерностей массива `map` используете магическое число `24`

```
unsigned char map[24][24]
                  ^^^^^^^
```

хотя список инициализации для каждой строки содержит только `sizeCol`, то есть 20 элементов. Например

```
{ 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, },
```

Не следует использовать магические числа, а надо использовать именованные константы. Для этого они и объявлены.

Кстати сказать, лучше эти константы объявить как статические члены класса

```
static const int sizeRow = 24;
static const int sizeCol = 20;
```

Также у вас расхождение между представлениями считываемых значений из файла как символов, тогда как в определении массива у вас заданы не символы, а целые числа.

Вы могли бы считывать данные из файла предварительно в некоторую переменную типа `unsigned int`, а затем ее значение присваивать элементу массива. Например

```
unsigned int value;

ifs >> value;
this->map[i][j] = value;
```

Comment: я переделал по вашим замечаниям, но вот в этом участке                    for (int i = 0; i < this->sizeRow; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < 24; j++) { не хочет работать, если ставлю sizeCol (20)

Comment: @jashka Не совсем понял, что в этом участке и почему опять используется число 24?

Comment: потому что без него вообще алгоритм не работает

Comment: @jashka Почему не работает? У вас есть константа sizeCol.

Comment: в том то и дело что если вместо 24 написать this->sizeCol, то алгоритм вообще не проходит лабиринт

Comment: @jashka Значит у вас неправильно работает алгоритм. Исследуйте его. Не должно быть в тексте программы этих магических чисел.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/29727/discussion-between-jashka-and-vlad-from-moscow).

Comment: @jashka  В принципе тут нечего обсуждать. Тут надо исправлять ошибки.:)

Answer (score 1):

Все очень просто: ваш текстовый файл содержит СИМВОЛЫ цифр, то есть состоит из байтов 0x31 или 0x30, к которым еще домешан пробел (0x20). Ваш заголовочный файл содержит массив, в котором записаны только байты 0x01 или 0x00. В итоге текстовик имеет ну совершенно иной формат.

Comment: как можно избежать этого ?

Comment: @jashka Как можно избежать чего именно? Другого формата? Создавайте текстовик в нужном формате, делов-то.